# Flink missing windows generated on some partitions

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to write a small Flink dataflow to understand more how it works and I am facing a strange situation where each time I run it, I am getting inconsistent outputs. Sometimes some  records that I am expecting are missing. Keep in mind this is just a toy example I am building to learn the concepts of the DataStream API.

I have a dataset of around 7600 rows in CSV format like that look like this:

```
Date,Country,City,Specie,count,min,max,median,variance
28/06/2021,GR,Athens,no2,116,0.5,58.9,5.5,2824.39
28/06/2021,GR,Athens,wind-speed,133,0.1,11.2,3,96.69
28/06/2021,GR,Athens,dew,24,14,20,18,35.92
28/06/2021,GR,Athens,temperature,141,24.4,38.4,30.5,123.18
28/06/2021,GR,Athens,pm25,116,34,85,68,702.29
```

Full dataset here: https://pastebin.com/rknnRnPc

There are no special characters or quotes, so a simple String split will work fine.

The date range for each city spans from 28/06/2021 to 03/10/2021.

I am reading it using the DataStream API:

`final DataStream<String> source = env.readTextFile("data.csv");`

Each row is mapped to a simple POJO as follows:

```
public class CityMetric {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

    private final LocalDate localDate;
    private final String country;
    private final String city;
    private final String reading;
    private final int count;
    private final double min;
    private final double max;
    private final double median;
    private final double variance;

    private CityMetric(LocalDate localDate, String country, String city, String reading, int count, double min, double max, double median, double variance) {
        this.localDate = localDate;
        this.country = country;
        this.city = city;
        this.reading = reading;
        this.count = count;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.median = median;
        this.variance = variance;
    }

    public static CityMetric fromArray(String[] arr) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(arr[0], dateFormatter);
        int count = Integer.parseInt(arr[4]);
        double min = Double.parseDouble(arr[5]);
        double max = Double.parseDouble(arr[6]);
        double median = Double.parseDouble(arr[7]);
        double variance = Double.parseDouble(arr[8]);

        return new CityMetric(date, arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], count, min, max, median, variance);
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return getLocalDate()
                .atStartOfDay()
                .toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                .toEpochMilli();
    }

//getters follow
```

The records are all in order of date, so I have this to set the event time and watermark:

```
   final WatermarkStrategy<CityMetric> cityMetricWatermarkStrategy =
            WatermarkStrategy.<CityMetric>forMonotonousTimestamps()  //we know they are sorted by time
                    .withTimestampAssigner((cityMetric, l) -> cityMetric.getTimestamp());
```

I have a `StreamingFileSink` on a Tuple4 to output the date range, city and average:

```
  final StreamingFileSink<Tuple4<LocalDate, LocalDate, String, Double>> fileSink =
        StreamingFileSink.forRowFormat(
                new Path("airquality"),
                new SimpleStringEncoder<Tuple4<LocalDate, LocalDate, String, Double>>("UTF-8"))
            .build();
```

And finally I have the dataflow as follows:

```
 source
        .map(s -> s.split(",")) //split the CSV row into its fields
        .filter(arr -> !arr[0].startsWith("Date")) // if it starts with Date it means it is the top header
        .map(CityMetric::fromArray)  //create the object from the fields
        .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(cityMetricWatermarkStrategy) // we use the date as the event time
        .filter(cm -> cm.getReading().equals("pm25")) // we want air quality of fine particulate matter pm2.5
        .keyBy(CityMetric::getCity) // partition by city name
        .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.days(7))) //windows of 7 days
        .aggregate(new CityAverageAggregate()) // average the values
        .name("cityair")
        .addSink(fileSink); //output each partition to a file
```

The `CityAverageAggregate` just accumulates the sum and count, and keeps track of the earliest and latest dates of the range it is covering.

```
public class CityAverageAggregate
    implements AggregateFunction<
        CityMetric, CityAverageAggregate.AverageAccumulator, Tuple4<LocalDate, LocalDate, String, Double>> {

  @Override
  public AverageAccumulator createAccumulator() {
    return new AverageAccumulator();
  }

  @Override
  public AverageAccumulator add(CityMetric cityMetric, AverageAccumulator averageAccumulator) {
    return averageAccumulator.add(
        cityMetric.getCity(), cityMetric.getLocalDate(), cityMetric.getMedian());
  }

  @Override
  public Tuple4<LocalDate, LocalDate, String, Double> getResult(
      AverageAccumulator averageAccumulator) {
    return Tuple4.of(
        averageAccumulator.getStart(),
        averageAccumulator.getEnd(),
        averageAccumulator.getCity(),
        averageAccumulator.average());
  }

  @Override
  public AverageAccumulator merge(AverageAccumulator acc1, AverageAccumulator acc2) {
    return acc1.merge(acc2);
  }

  public static class AverageAccumulator {
    private final String city;
    private final LocalDate start;
    private final LocalDate end;
    private final long count;
    private final double sum;

    public AverageAccumulator() {
      city = "";
      count = 0;
      sum = 0;
      start = null;
      end = null;
    }

    AverageAccumulator(String city, LocalDate start, LocalDate end, long count, double sum) {
      this.city = city;
      this.count = count;
      this.sum = sum;
      this.start = start;
      this.end = end;
    }

    public AverageAccumulator add(String city, LocalDate eventDate, double value) {
      //make sure our dataflow is correct and we are summing data from the same city
      if (!this.city.equals("") && !this.city.equals(city)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(city + " does not match " + this.city);
      }

      return new AverageAccumulator(
          city,
          earliest(this.start, eventDate),
          latest(this.end, eventDate),
          this.count + 1,
          this.sum + value);
    }

    public AverageAccumulator merge(AverageAccumulator that) {
      LocalDate mergedStart = earliest(this.start, that.start);
      LocalDate mergedEnd = latest(this.end, that.end);
      return new AverageAccumulator(
          this.city, mergedStart, mergedEnd, this.count + that.count, this.sum + that.sum);
    }

    private LocalDate earliest(LocalDate d1, LocalDate d2) {
      if (d1 == null) {
        return d2;
      } else if (d2 == null) {
        return d1;
      } else {
        return d1.isBefore(d2) ? d1 : d2;
      }
    }

    private LocalDate latest(LocalDate d1, LocalDate d2) {
      if (d1 == null) {
        return d2;
      } else if (d2 == null) {
        return d1;
      } else {
        return d1.isAfter(d2) ? d1 : d2;
      }
    }

    public double average() {
      return sum / count;
    }

    public String getCity() {
      return city;
    }

    public LocalDate getStart() {
      return start;
    }

    public LocalDate getEnd() {
      return end;
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem:**

The problem I am facing is that sometimes I do not get all the windows I am expecting. This does not always happen, sometimes consecutive runs output a different result, so I am suspecting there is some race condition somewhere.

For example, in one of the partition file output I sometimes get:

```
(2021-07-12,2021-07-14,Belgrade,56.666666666666664)
(2021-07-15,2021-07-21,Belgrade,56.0)
(2021-07-22,2021-07-28,Belgrade,57.285714285714285)
(2021-07-29,2021-08-04,Belgrade,43.57142857142857)
(2021-08-05,2021-08-11,Belgrade,35.42857142857143)
(2021-08-12,2021-08-18,Belgrade,43.42857142857143)
(2021-08-19,2021-08-25,Belgrade,36.857142857142854)
(2021-08-26,2021-09-01,Belgrade,50.285714285714285)
(2021-09-02,2021-09-08,Belgrade,46.285714285714285)
(2021-09-09,2021-09-15,Belgrade,54.857142857142854)
(2021-09-16,2021-09-22,Belgrade,56.714285714285715)
(2021-09-23,2021-09-29,Belgrade,59.285714285714285)
(2021-09-30,2021-10-03,Belgrade,61.5)
```

While sometimes I get the full set:

```
(2021-06-28,2021-06-30,Belgrade,48.666666666666664)
(2021-07-01,2021-07-07,Belgrade,41.142857142857146)
(2021-07-08,2021-07-14,Belgrade,52.857142857142854)
(2021-07-15,2021-07-21,Belgrade,56.0)
(2021-07-22,2021-07-28,Belgrade,57.285714285714285)
(2021-07-29,2021-08-04,Belgrade,43.57142857142857)
(2021-08-05,2021-08-11,Belgrade,35.42857142857143)
(2021-08-12,2021-08-18,Belgrade,43.42857142857143)
(2021-08-19,2021-08-25,Belgrade,36.857142857142854)
(2021-08-26,2021-09-01,Belgrade,50.285714285714285)
(2021-09-02,2021-09-08,Belgrade,46.285714285714285)
(2021-09-09,2021-09-15,Belgrade,54.857142857142854)
(2021-09-16,2021-09-22,Belgrade,56.714285714285715)
(2021-09-23,2021-09-29,Belgrade,59.285714285714285)
(2021-09-30,2021-10-03,Belgrade,61.5)
```

Is there anything evidently wrong in my dataflow pipeline? Can't figure out why this would happen. It doesn't always happen on the same city either.

What could be happening?

**UPDATE**

So it seems that when I disabled Watermarks the problem didn't happen any more. I changed the WatermarkStrategy to the following:

```
    final WatermarkStrategy<CityMetric> cityMetricWatermarkStrategy =
            WatermarkStrategy.<CityMetric>noWatermarks()  
                             .withTimestampAssigner((cityMetric, l) -> cityMetric.getTimestamp());
```

And so far I have been getting consistent results. When I checked the [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/eventtime/WatermarkStrategy.html#noWatermarks--) it says that:

> static  WatermarkStrategy noWatermarks()
>
> Creates a watermark strategy that generates no watermarks at all. This may be useful in scenarios that do pure processing-time based stream processing.

But I am not doing processing-time based stream processing, I am doing event-time processing.

Why would [`forMonotonousTimestamps()`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/eventtime/WatermarkStrategy.html#forMonotonousTimestamps--) have the strange behaviour I was seeing? Indeed my timestamps are monotonically increasing (the `noWatermarks` strategy wouldn't work if they weren't), but somehow changing this does not work well with my scenario.

Is there anything I am missing with the way things work in Flink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink doesn't support per-key watermarking. Each parallel task generates watermarks independently, based on observing all of the events flowing through that task.

So the reason this isn't working with the `forMonotonousTimestamps` watermark strategy is that the input is not actually in order by timestamp. It is temporally sorted *within each city*, but not globally. This is then going to result in some records being late, but unpredictably so, depending on exactly when watermarks are generated. These late events are being ignored by the windows that should contain them.

You can address this in a number of ways:

(1) Use a `forBoundedOutOfOrderness` watermark strategy with a duration sufficient to account for the actual out-of-order-ness in the dataset. Given that the data looks something like this:

```
03/10/2021,GR,Athens,pressure,60,1017.9,1040.6,1020.9,542.4
28/06/2021,US,Atlanta,co,24,1.4,7.3,2.2,19.05
```

that will require an out-of-order-ness duration of approximately 100 days.

(2) Configure the windows to have sufficient allowed lateness. This will result in some of the windows being triggered multiple times -- once when the watermark indicates they can close, and again each time a late event is added to the window.

(3) Use the `noWatermarks` strategy. This will lead to the job only producing results if and when it reaches the end of its input file(s). For a continuous streaming job this wouldn't be workable, but for finite (bounded) inputs this can work.

(4) Run the job in `RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH` mode. Then the job will only produce results at the end, after having consumed all of its input. This will run the job with a more optimized runtime designed for batch workloads, but the outcome should be the same as with (3).

(5) Change the input so it isn't out-of-order.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All my code is included so it should be fully reproducable. I could try and attach the CSV file something if that is the only thing missing, but the format is as I included, I guess it can be any random data as long as it is ordered by date. I know the Table API is better suited, but the intention of this exercise is just for me to learn how Flink Datastream API works, it is not a real use case, just a data source for some data. I will try to switch to `FileSource`. Still would be nice to understand why this is happening, really hate not to understand why.

Comment: The specific data and the parallelism could have an impact on reproducing this, and perhaps other factors I'm overlooking.

Comment: Full data set here: https://pastebin.com/rknnRnPc

Comment: Now I see what's going on and have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. So even though they are partitioned, one partition's watermark still influences the other? What I wanted to do there is see that each partition's event time and windowing is independent (maybe it was a bit extreme here, but I was just playing around). I wanted to simulate that a sensor might be offline and then send a burst of data readings. Why would a watermark of one key influence the watermark of another, if the windowing is taking place per key?

Comment: See the first (short) paragraph that I just added. Flink's watermarking doesn't pay any attention to key partitioning. Typically watermarking is done in the sources, while keyBy is applied later in the pipeline.